# Validate HTML with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I use BeautifulSoup 3.2.1 to parse a lot of HTML files translated with eTranslation.

I found
`soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file, "html.parser")` sometimes cuts a section of my HTML file. And it is related to invalid tags or problems found in the HTML.

Also I found `soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file, "lxml")` works better in these cases of bad written HTML.

Is there a way to detect which HTML file is invalid using BeautifulSoup?

I image something like this:

```
if valid(html_file):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file, "html.parser")
else:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file, "lxml")
```

Comment: As explained here https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers, different parsers will give you differents results. For instance html.parser will ignore orphelans tags because your HTML is not well-formatted.
Maybe you can try 'html5lib' parser as suggested in the documentation ?

Comment: Also you've got the diagnose() method that can help you : https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#diagnose

Comment: I solved it using lxml all the time. It seems OK in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did. Since BeautifulSoup fixes invalid HTML when parsing comparing it to the original gives an answer if it was valid.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def is_valid_HTML_tag(html_string_to_check: str) -> bool:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_string_to_check, 'html.parser')
    return True if html_string_to_check == str(soup) else False

print(is_valid_HTML_tag('<div>valid</div>'))
print(is_valid_HTML_tag('<div>invalid'))
```

gives

```
True  

False
```

respectively

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using lxml all the time.

Comment: That was my first thought when I read your question, lol.